# Main Class Is In JAR, Can't Be Seen By Jar.exe

Tags: java, jar

To put it simply, I have a *different* error where Eclipse won't allow me to export the recent version of a JAR. So, I'm trying in command prompt instead.

I'm using JDK 1.8.0.

1) First, I extracted all class files from their individual folders.
2) I created a manifest.txt which contains the following (**including a carriage return at the end as described in the oracle tutorial**)

```
Main-Class: Start
```

3) I'm creating the runnable jar with the following command, being verbose as possible to ensure correct versioning:

```
C:\correctDirectory\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\jar.exe" cvfm ERSR.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

4) That runs fine. I then inspect the JAR to ensure it containts the Start.class file which contains the main method:

```
C:\correctDirectory\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\jar.exe" tf ERSR.jar
```

The output of that is (reduced to useful info):

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Start.class
```

5) Then I run the JAR with the following command:

```
C:\correctDirectory\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java" -jar ERSR.jar
```

To which I get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Start.
```

Thanks in advance kind folks.

Comment: The Start class is in the package "Test" ?

Comment: Yes (added the rest of the sentence to meet minimum req).

Comment: Can you add the output you got in step 4?

Comment: Package names should be lowercase. Is there a directory named `Test` in the jar that contains `Start.class`?

Comment: Is the class `Start` and the method `main` both declared `public`?

Comment: @davida. I will add the relevent sections now.

Comment: I removed the package information, ran the commands again without packages, same problem. Removed the `Test` package information from the question.

Comment: Your class is in the wrong directory with regards to the package.

Comment: @KenReid, does your Start class contain any static field that is initialized with a contents of a resource (a .properties file, or alike) ?

Comment: It does @davida. - I take it that's the cause then. Nice catch!

Comment: I made the field non static, updated it to a new object etc, and still have the same issue sadly.

Comment: The error is quite clear, the main class can't be found. It doesn't matter what the class contains, it **can't be found**. Now I recommend you invent yourself a proper package, you can use your imagination here, like `package ken.reid;` then make sure you have `ken\reid\Start.class` inside the jar, and `ken.reid.Start` as the `Main-Class` argument in the manifest file.

Comment: It can't be found, or it can't be loaded. Which also might be because a static field of that class can't be initialized. I posted my answer.

Comment: An initialization error would give a stacktrace. Given the random configuration presented here, I'll bet you dollars to donuts that it's not related to the actual code in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Start class contain any static field that is initialized with a contents of a resource (a .properties file, or alike)?

If that is the case, then it's likely the problem. The command you use in step 3) only packages the .class files into the JAR, but ignores the rest:

`...\jar.exe cvfm ERSR.jar manifest.txt *.class`

Modify it to include everything:

`...\jar.exe cvfm ERSR.jar manifest.txt *`